# How can ı resolve my nested div hover problem in css

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
#main_div {
    background-color: #333;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 12px 12px 18px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 12px 12px 18px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 12px 18px #000;
    border-left: 5px solid orange;
    border-top: 5px solid orange;
    height: 800px;
}
    
a {
  background-color: orange !important;
}

a:hover {
    border-left: 5px solid darkorange !important;
    border-top: 5px solid darkorange !important;
    transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="main_div">
    <a href"#">
         <div><span>Hello World!</span></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to hover div. "a" is growing in hover position. But I have a problem As a grows, `main_div` grows with it. How do I prevent `main_div` from growing.

Comment: The wrapper ```div``` is not growing because you use ```scale```, but because you are adding ```border-width``` on ```:hover```. Add the border on your element and only change the color on hover, you can set this color to transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above, try giving the border already some width and simply change its color on hover.

```css
#main_div {
  background: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_div">
    <a href"#">
         <div><span>Hello World!</span></div>
    </a>
</div>
```